# Reading names on 1912 City of Chicago death certificate?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, jewish, illinois

What are the names of the father and mother on this death 1912 death certificate?

[image: Illegible portion of death certificate]

Her husband was known to have been born in Kiev, so it is likely she and her family are from Kiev (despite the certificate listing a birth place of Russia). She was Jewish.

Here is the full certificate:

[image: Certificate and Record of Death of Jennie Trachtenberg]

As a hint to the handwriting, the name of the deceased is Jennie Trachtenberg.

Answer (score 1):

Those are tough. I read the father;'s first name as "Arie" and the mother's as "Amy". No guesses as to the last names. However, you have several hints: Jennie married a guy by the name of Trachtenberg. Can you locate a marriage record? That would show her maiden name, if not the names of the parents. She lived in Chicago, 1156 Hasting(s?) St. What do census records say? Even if she had just arrived in 1907, the 1910 US census should list them. She was 54 years old and a housewife. She would likely have been married to Trachtenberg for some time, and they might have arrived in the US together. Can you find immigration records for 1907?

Comment: Thanks for trying. She was married back in the old country (Ukraine), for which there are no records. Her parents did not accompany them to the United States.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Many, many Jewish Ukrainian records *did* survive, including from the Kyiv area.